# Setting required FFT spectrum bandwidth w.r.t the Sampling rate

Tags: fft

I am working on an accelerometer with sampling rate of 26.7 kHz using which I intend to calculate FFT. Hence the FMax =  (26.7/2.56 = 10.4kHz). As I am performing this on a microcontroller, I have a limitation that I can only compute 2048-point FFT where my LOR(Lines of Resolution) is 2048/2.56 = 800.

Now the problem is that my deltaF = 10400/800 = 13Hz, which is a very low resolution hence I cannot go ahead with this solution.  Also my requirement is to calculate FFT upto 1 kHz ​where my deltaF will be 1000/800 = 1.25Hz, which is acceptable to me.

So is it possible to reduce FMax of my spectrum from 10.4 kHz to 1 kHz with the abovementioned sampling rate of the sensor?

FYI,

The sensor has an inbuilt LPF which I can implement at 1 kHz.

Comment: Sorry, this is hard to understand. Where does the "2.56" come from ?

Comment: +1, the Nyquist frequency should be Fs/2, I dunno where the 2.56 comes from. I think it is possible to resample the signal to Fs=2 kHz and then compute a 2048-point FFT.

Comment: 2.56 is the Nyquist coefficient. Theoretically it is considered 2 but practically roll-off factor of 0.5 is considered, but in order to comply with the computer world, 2.56 is usually the number used.